# Right align the last of several inline-block

Tags: html, css

If I have an unordered list with 5 list items. The list items are set to `display: inline-block` so that they will stack horisontally, left aligned.

But if I want the very last list item to be right aligned. Is there a good way to do this without using float?

Comment: What's wrong with floating the last element?

Comment: A code example could be really helpful here, as any answer I have is guessing at what you are actually after

Comment: Floating the last element works fine... Its just that I was hoping I could do this without a clearfloat on the parent container =)

Answer (score 0):

You can use psudeo-element [**::before**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) to clear float. Take a look to the following example using [**last-child**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child):

```css
ul li {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
}
ul li:last-child {
  float: right;
}
ul li:last-child:before {
  content: '';
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using the float, you can do this way:

```
li:last-child {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
}
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/49pcmwhv/)

P.S You can change the value of "right" if you wanna put the last item closer to the other li's or closer to the border